# Binary logistic regression: significance without an increase in Overall Percentage?

Tags: logistic-regression, spss

I have some data that with two independent variables and one dependent. I'm using SPSS and my IVs have interaction. My results are below.

I don't have a stats background and am new to LG, so not sure how to interpret my results. Specifically, as I highlight below, the data seems to have significance (χ2(1) = 7.737, p = .005), but the Overall Percentage for the model is the same as the Null Hypothesis (60.0)?

Am I doing something wrong or can binary LG show significance in the data without a bump in Overall Percentage?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. I see you are entering only the interaction term "Attraction_1Yes2No * Crush_1_Yes2_No".
   You should enter those two independent variables as well: Attraction_1Yes2No AND Crush_1_Yes2_No.
2. Are those independent variables categoric? Then you should tell that in the "categoric" dialog box, specificating the reference category for each one.
3. Your dependent variable original values are 1 and 3. The procedure is pointing to value 3 as its target . Is that the category you want to predict? If not, recode prior to running again the regression.
4. It is possible to enter a significant variable without benefits in classification (it also depends on the cut value). But first check these items and tell results